# Apply thresholding logic to one column of NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D NumPy array which is essentially image data in RGBA format like so:

```
[
  [
    [233 228 230 120]
    [233 228 230 0]
    [232 227 229 212]
    ...
  ]
  ...
]
```

In the example above the last (4th) column represents alpha channel. As I can't have semi-transparent pixels (value other than 0 or 255), I need to threshold that column. Any value below 255 should become 0.

What I have is the line below.

```
image[...,3][image[...,3] < 255] = 0
```

It does work but I wanted to ask if there is something shorter and more elegant that would do the job. Thanks.

Comment: can you post your image shape?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: @Lior Cohen was indeed right! Apologies.

```
# if your channels are in the last axis, this should work
image[:,:,3][image[:,:,3] < 255] = 0

# another alternative, but not as elegant as what @Lior proposed
image[:,:,3] = np.where(image[:,:,3] < 255, 0, 255)
```

Comment: I think this will truncate the RGB to 0 and not only the alpha

Comment: @LiorCohen you were right! I overlooked it. Your answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Two More options that are based on the `/255` operator which will cut integer lower than 255 to 0.

1. ```
   image[...,3] = image[...,3] // 255 * 255
   ```
2. ```
   image[...,3] //= 255
   image[...,3] *= 255
   ```